# Booting Ubuntu In EFI

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, grub-efi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. (I know its the old LTS version but it is the last LTS that runs well on my device.) However when i boot using a USB and run

`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"`

it returns `EFI boot on HDD` which is how i need the system to be installed. However when it comes to installing grub and i chroot into the system and run the same command it returns `Legacy boot on HDD`. This then prevents me from installing grub.

Also i am not trying to dual-boot i would like this as my main OS.

I kind of know my way around linux but this has really baffled me.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  Better to use 16.04.1 or newest. Otherwise your 16.04.2 is obsolete as it only supported until 16.04.3 came out. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack  And if not getting kernel updates, you have missing the fixes for Meltdown and Spectre CPU vulnerabilities.

Comment: Here is the link to the summary report. /dev/sda1 is the bootable USB and /dev/mmcblk1 is the drive where the OS is installed. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QYKRG2bwKs/

Comment: Actually p1 is the ESP - efi system partition and p3 is your Linux / (root) partition. I would let Boot-Repair do the full reinstall of grub. Be sure to be booted in UEFI mode with Ubuntu live installer.  Best to use current versions of Ubuntu, as you get errors with versions not supported anymore.

Comment: I have tried this but still grub hasn't installed properly. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h3KHTnDhH2/ Here is the link to the summary.

Comment: Please help @oldfred ?

Comment: It looks like you have updated grub and now have an Ubuntu entry in UEFI boot menu. Can you boot that directly from UEFI menu? What brand/model system.

Comment: Brand: Toshiba. I dont have a UEFI boot menu i only see the drive and thats it. When i go to boot from the drive is says `No bootable device found`

Comment: Is there a icon showing more entries under hard drive? Have you updated UEFI. Many have to update UEFI to have boot entry.